# Jquery scroll top animate not going to desired location / scrolling up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a feature of my music player that centers the track / div you click on in the scroll-able parent div. For some reason it does not always scroll to the center, it will scroll crazy to the top in the same spot when I scroll down and click a track that is lower. The main purpose of this feature is so that users that start exploring tracks don't have to scroll. It enhances the UX overall. How can I make it so when clicked it scrolls to the track that is clicked and vertically centers it to the middle of the parent div? (Also this will be added to the next and prev buttons as you can see in the demo)

**Live Demo:**  http://loopcove.com/playerupdated2020.php?id=30

```
$(".playbox").on('click', function () {
      if (!$(this).hasClass('playboxplaylight') && $(this) !== nowplay) {$('.scrollit').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() 
    },1000);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your scroller is not scrolling to the correct position is the scroll plugin you're using.
This plugin disables the native scroll and uses translate to scroll the page smoothly.
This makes the jQuery's `.offset()` function to return wrong values. 
The solution to get the right values is

```
$(".playbox").on('click', function () {
    // Your if checks here
    $('.scrollit').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this)[0].offsetTop - $(this).height() 
    },1000);
})
```

But the above code still doesn't center the scroll pixel perfectly. To do that, you've to subtract the heights of the topbar and the bottom bor.

```
$(".playbox").on('click', function () {
    // Your if checks here
    $('.scrollit').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this)[0].offsetTop - $(this).height() - ($('.menu-search-box').height() + $('.play-bar').height())
    },1000);
})
```